# TypeError: t.map is not a function react-dom.production.min.js:216

Tags: javascript, reactjs, production, react-scripts

I'm working on a MERN stack application, and when I run the app locally everything works fine, but when I build the React app with `npm run build` and I serve it with `serve -s build`, some pages are working and some are not, the error in the console shows:

```
TypeError: t.map is not a function
    at j (PersonList.js:44)
    at ig (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Vg (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
    at Ga (react-dom.production.min.js:269)
    at Es (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at _s (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at ks (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at ds (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at e.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
```

I tried to downgrade the react-scripts but when I do `npm install` it tells me there's a lot of deprecations etc.

Any ideas why this doesn't work in production?